# A question about divergent series related to the harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I was thinking about slowly diverging series.  I came up with this idea but I don't know what it's called or where to look.

Suppose you start with the harmonic series:

$$\sum_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots$$

this diverges fairly slowly.  Now we remove geometric series, seriatim. We know that a geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^n$ converges if $|r| < 1$. So, remove first $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots$ leaving:

$$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \cdots$$

then remove $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots $, leaving

$$\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \cdots$$

and so on. That is, after each removal, we remove a geometric series that begins with the first term that remains in the series. So, we next remove $\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{25} + \cdots $, then $\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{36} + \cdots$

Since we are removing convergent series, no matter how many we remove (as long as its not uncountably many), the result is still divergent.

Has this series been studied?

Comment: "Since we are removing convergent series, no matter how many we remove, the result is still divergent". It actually matter if u want to remove uncountable many of them

Comment: What is there to study? As you say, the series you get are divergent. What more would you like to say about them?

Comment: @DominikKutek  Right. I will edit.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I'm not sure. I was just thinking about it and wondering if it was of any interest in math or not. (I am a statistician, not a mathematician).

Comment: Your description could use a little tightening-up in places. For instance, what does "and so on" mean? Are you removing reciprocals of powers of *all integers* $2$, $3$, $4$, $\cdots$, or just *primes* $2$, $3$, $5$, $\cdots$? Also, how do you account for the fact that you remove $1$ with $1/2$, but not with $1/3$? (BTW: If you're removing series indexed by integers, you can be assured that you won't be removing uncountably many of them.)

Comment: @Blue is it better now?

Comment: @PeterFlom: The description of the removal process is better, thanks. However, your point isn't clear (to me). I guess it seems paradoxical, starting with a divergent sum and incrementally removing finite sub-sums to get ... *what?* A series evidently with no terms and, thus, a value of 0? Yet each step removed a finite value from an infinite preceding sum ... *What's up with that?* If that's what you're driving at, the geometric sub-sums seem an unnecessary complication; you could just as well have removed only the first term at each step. So, maybe you're getting at something else.

Comment: So, you ask, "Has this series been studied". Which series? You have described a process for generating a list of series, but I don't know what you mean by "this series". If you mean, the series that remains after you have removed all your geometric series, well, nothing remains after you have removed all those geometric series, just the empty series, so there's nothing left to study.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I don't know exactly.  But, no matter how much we remove, the series diverges. That just seemed weird to me, but maybe I am the only one.

Comment: So long as you only remove finitely many geometric series, yes, the remaining series diverges. But even if I grant you that that's a weird state of affairs, I still don't know what you mean by "has this series been studied?" I still don't know which series you are referring to, when you write, "this series".

Comment: OK, maybe I should have written "this idea" rather than "this series".

Comment: We're making progress. Only, now I don't know which idea you are referring to. Certainly the idea that if you delete a convergent series (or a finite number of convergent series, which is the same thing) from a divergent series you still have a divergent series, is well-known.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the responses.Maybe I should share the genesis of my post. Over on Quora there there was a question about "slowest diverging" series and several mathematicians answered that there isn't one. But that got me thinking that the harmonic series is a slowly diverging series that is pretty famous and easy to describe and so on. But then I thought it's weird that you could subtract stuff from it and have it still diverge - even more slowly.  But, apparently, this idea isn't all that interesting.